# When transitioning from Google+ authentication to GIDSignIn, do I need to get new clientIDs?

Tags: google-plus, clientid

Can I continue to use the same clientID I was using with Google+ with GIDSignIn? It seems to work, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

The `clientID` is the ID of your app, and does not change.

You may wish to make sure that this clientID in the Google Cloud Console is not using any of the Google+ APIs or scopes, but otherwise you should be fine.